# BASH script to rename XML file to an attribute value

Tags: regex, xml, bash, file

I have ***a lot*** of `.xml` files structured the same way:

```
<parent id="idvalue" attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ...>
    <child attr3="val3" attr4="val4" ... />
    <child attr3="val5" attr4="val6" ... />
    ...
</parent>
```

Each file has exactly one `<parent>` element with exactly one `id` attribute.

All of those files (almost 1,700,000 of them) are named as part.xxxxx where xxxxx is a random number.

I want to name each of those files as `idvalue.xml`, according to the sole `id` attribute from the file's content.

I believe doing it with a bash script would be the fastest and most automated way. But if there are other suggestions, I would love to hear them.

My main problem is that I am not able (don't know how) to get the `idvalue` in a specific file, so that I could use it with the `mv file.xxxxx idvalue.xml` command.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried?

Comment: @Celos I tried to create a bash script which would rename each file in a `for fn` loop, but I am not able to read the `idvalue` from a specific file. I've added more information to my question, please have a look.

Comment: I was giving a shot with XSLT but i guess bash script will perform faster than XSLT since XSLT makes use of external libraries to run (just my guess). But I would recommend that you give a try once with XSLT as well

Comment: @Meghaa I was planning to explore XSLT for some time now. It's always lack of time available that's a problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would iterate through the xml files using `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name 'part*.xml' -exec ./rename_xml.sh {} \;
```

The line above will execute `rename_xml.sh` for every xml file, passing the file name as command argument to the script.

`rename_xml.sh` should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

// Get the id using XPath. You might probably need 
// to install xmllint for that if it is not already present.
// The xpath query will return a string like this (try it!):
//
//     id="idvalue"
//
// We are using sed to extract the value from  that
id=$(xmllint --xpath '//parent/@id' "$1" | sed -r 's/[^"]+"([^"]+).*/\1/')
mv -v "$1" "$id.xml"
```

Don't forget to

```
chmod +x rename_xml.sh
```

Comment: this seems to be working. Thanks. I just have a question. In `rename_xml.sh` you refer to the id attribute through `//parent/@id` syntax. What if different files have different `parent` elements? Can I use a wild card instead of the element name, something like `//*/@id`?

Comment: do you always refer to the id attribute of the *root* element of the xml?

Comment: Hm, I think so, yes. I'm still not positive for all of the 1.7mil. of them :/ But for those that I've checked, yes. EDIT: Actually, yes, I think it's safe to presume that `id` will always be in the root element.

Comment: `/*/@id` should work in this case. If there is only one id element in the xml regardless of it's position you can use `//*/@id`.

Comment: This is great news. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper XML handling tool to extract the id from the files. For example,
[xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
for file in part.* ; do
    mv "$file" $(xsh -aC 'open { shift }; echo /parent/@id' "$file").xml
done
```

Comment: `xsh` looks promising, one day I'll try it! ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl agreed. Unfortunately I had trouble installing it on my elementary OS. I'm going to upvote your solution, so I could remember to get back to it and learn XSH. But at this moment the other answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment that I am not sure about the performance of  XSLT in compared to bash scripts, but I created the XSLT for you to try out.

In the stylesheet below, Dire is the directory that contains the xml files.The select "tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"
retrieves the filename and the second line concatenates the directory name with the filename to get the path of the file.The line with xsl:copy..is used to copy the entire xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:random="http://www.microsoft.com/msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:for-each select="collection('Dire/?select=*.xml')" >
           <xsl:variable name="filename" select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
           <xsl:variable name="filepath" select="concat('Dire/',$filename)"/>
           <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document($filepath)"/>
           <xsl:variable name="outname" select="$doc/parent/@id"/>
           <xsl:result-document href="{$outname}.xml" method="xml">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$doc/node()"/>
           </xsl:result-document>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I ran the xslt using saxon8. Unfortunately I could not find any way to rename the xml directly.But the above code should be worth a try.