# Rename XML files based on contents of an element

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xpath

I'm trying to use [hek2mgl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718683/bash-script-to-rename-xml-file-to-an-attribute-value) to a previous question and am getting an error message I hope you can help me with.

What I am trying to do: rename XML files so they reflect the contents of the identifier element.

This is the exact code I am using:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'part*.xml' -exec ./rename_xml.sh {} \;
```

While my rename_xml script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$(xmllint --xpath '//identifier' "$1" | sed -r 's/[^"]+"([^"]+).*/\1/')
mv -v "$1" "$id.xml"
```

A sample source XML file looks like this:

```
<root>
   <title>title</title>
   <identifier>001</identifier>
</root>
```

I get the following error message when I run the find command.

```
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
XPath set is empty
./.xml -> .xml
```

My guess it that there are two things happening here - a non-working version of sed (illegal -r option), and a problem with my XPath. How can I change this script to work as intended?

Comment: I want to do exactly what it says in the title of the question: Rename XML files based on contents of an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for ya?

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -name "part*.xml" | while read file
do
   id=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//identifier)' $file)
   echo "mv $file $id.xml"
   mv $file $id.xml
done
```

Comment: Adam vonNieda, this works perfectly, and I think I understand how it works except for the presence of $file at the end of line 5. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, that's just telling xmllint what file it's working on. Please mark as correct if you don't mind ;)